# How to enable network on Ubuntu? I installed Ubuntu Server without select any package

Tags: networking, server, system-installation

I hit ENTER on tasksel without select any package at Ubuntu Server's installation. Now when system booted I have no network connection. How can I enable network now, so I can install the packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system comes with `dhclient`, even if I haven't selected any package.

So to enable network run:

`sudo dhclient`**eth0** (the name of your network card)

Then:

`sudo apt update`

and later:

`sudo tasksel install server` or just `sudo tasksel` and select desired packages

ps.: You can check the name of avaiable network card with `ip addr` command